# Can you use Github Desktop to create a local repository only

Tags: github, version-control, github-desktop

We are looking to set-up source control on a Windows remote development server.  The source code should never leave this server.  Can we use Github Desktop in this scenario to simply manage a local repository and never send the code off the server?  If not, is there some other simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `is there some other simple way to achieve this?` Like `git`?

Comment: Its running on Windows, and ideally we'd prefer to have a GUI to work with.